# How can I use XMLReader to read number of elements below specific node element?

Tags: c#, .net, xmldocument, xmlreader, xelement

Lets say you have the following xml convention which can't be replaced:
Each class is represented By `<Class>` and HashCode attribute.
The name of the class is right below the `<Class>` tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Class HashCode="1">
  <Person>
    <Class HashCode="-3">
      <FullName>
        <FirstName>Dan</FirstName>
        <LastName>K</LastName>
      </FullName>
    </Class>
    <Age>20</Age>
    <Class HashCode="4">
      <Address>
        <Street>abc</Street>
        <City>new york</City>
        <ZipCode>30500</ZipCode>
        <PhoneNumber>1245</PhoneNumber>
      </Address>
    </Class>
 </Person>
```

**Question**: How can I use `XMLReader` object in order to read the number of Node elements after a given element, until I reach an element tag which wasn't followed by `<Class>` tag.

**For example**:
Starting at `<FullName>` will automatically stop at `<LastName>` (because one tag before there is no `<Class>` tag) and return the number of elements between them which I guess is 1.

**Assumption:**  Consider you have the start tag's `Hashcode` value and Name which will come of course one level after `<Class Hashcode=>` tag.

I tried many things with `XMLReader` methods and got complicated, was trying to convert to `XMLDocument` with `XMlReader.ReadSubtree()` but seems that `XMLDocument` didn't help me also.

Comment: Do you have to use an xmlReader?  Can you use a XDocument?

Comment: As I mentioned I was able to create XMLDocument from the relevant element start point by `ReadSubTree()`.
trying to continue from there with no success

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @DavidBasarab: Do you have any clue?

Comment: @JohnSaunders: Do you have any idea?

Comment: Do you want to get all the instances of Class? as an array?

Comment: @AdrianSalazar: I don't want to get instances, I have an XML stream, and I want read the number of Node elements after a given element, until I reach an element tag which wasn't followed by <Class>.
See above example for more details , if still something not clear please tell me

Comment: I have no idea what you want. Yes I see the XML in example, but I need sample output as well. Numbers...

Comment: ok I will try again, I have hierarchical xml tree, as you see above.
<Person> says there is class named person, how do I know it's a class?
Answer: this <Person> tag is nested after <Class> tag with hashcode =1.
FullName is also a class from the same reasons, first name is not a class and represent a value type/or string how do we know that?
Answer: It is not followed directly after <Class hashcode> tag. it because it is followed after FullName.

Comment: @AdrianSalazar:  I want to be able to know the following how many XML elemnets (which are the tags) there is between startElement which I give to you say FullName till the next value type or string tag.
In our example it is 1.(will stop at firstName)

Comment: Another example start at <Person> tag, You will have to stop counting when reaching to <FirstName> also but you will return 3

Comment: You're missing the closing `</Class>`.

Comment: I tried to edit this post and to add it, in real XML I have it
it's not the issue

Comment: Assume you just read the whole thing into an XDocument. If you did that, then what problem would you have? What are you trying to find? For instance, it's easy to get a collection of all of the first child element of each `Class` element. That would return you {Person, FullName, Address}. What are you ultimately trying to _do_ with this information?

Comment: @JohnSaunders: I'm trying to find the first element tag which not represent a class which means is not followed by <Class> tag parent (one level up directly only) for <person> it will be <firstName>

Comment: So, in  your example, you're looking for `FullName`?

Comment: No, I have an XmlReader object which already pointing to it
I want to go to firstName so I need to know how many element should I iterate forward, so the function in the other post should explore the way between them and return answer, in our situation it is 1

Comment: @JohnSaunders: Just to clarify I was talking now specifically. In general I want to be able to explore iteratively from given tag to the first tag which is not class and how many elements were in the way, So I will know how much times I need to move the reader pointer to get there by `reader.ReadStartElement()`

Comment: In my example I'm looking for FirstName which is representing a string value in class, it is in FullName Class that's why I don't want FullName, I want first Value or string variable and this is firstName

Comment: @JohnSaunders: One correction about three comments above..
if you start at `<Person>` you should stop at `<firstName>` returning 3 not 1 my mistake, 1 is for example you start at `<fullName>` and stop at `<firstName>`from the same reasons

Comment: It seems a job for a SAX parser. You can simulate it in .NET; take a look at this article: http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_data/xml/article.php/c4221/Writing-XML-SAX-Parsers-in-C.htm